# Can't show viewcontroller from UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Basically I have a CollectionView inside a tableviewcell and Here's the method I'm using to push to another viewcontroller.

**Here's the code** :

```
class recipeRelated: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {       
       let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
       let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "recipeContainerView") as! recipeContainerView
       self.window?.rootViewController?.show(resultViewController,sender: self)
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please download a collection view example project from github to easily understand how you should hook everything up, found this for you: https://github.com/rainaakshay/DynamicCollectionViewSwift4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this extension:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This will give any view access to it's first parent controller. So you can use it like this:

```
self.parentViewController?.show(resultViewController, sender: self)
```